# Compare goldbolt and MSVC C++ version

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, version, godbolt

I have written some code that compiles on godbolt, but does not compile in Microsoft Visual Studio. I am trying to figure out why. My first step was to compare compiler versions. On goldbolt, I am compiling the code using "x64 msvc v19.latest." I googled "how to check msvc version," and all of the directions I can find lead me to the MSVS version, which is 17.2.6.

How can I find my MSVC version that is comparable to the godbolt version?

Comment: It [compiles fine here](https://www.godbolt.org/z/3GnM6eGTx).  You are probably using invalid command-line options for MSVC.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my link just leads to goldbolt.org. There is no code included in the question.

Comment: Please post the code.  For example, this: `int size = 10; int arr[size];` will also compile using g++, but will fail to compile with MSVC, with the reason being that the code is not valid C++, but g++ accepts the non-standard VLA syntax.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I appreciate the offer to help with fixing the bug, but this post is just about comparing compiler versions. Unless you happen to be one of the <50 people who understand MSVC's implementation of coroutines, I'd rather not post the code.

Comment: I think it will compile fine, but to get it to run you will need to add a main 'int main()` method.  Like this : https://www.godbolt.org/z/K5KqbP1ah. I also opened the output view  (bottom left output button) and enabled execute in output drop down menu

Comment: @PepijnKramer there is no code in the OP. Just a link to godbolt.org. To prevent confusion in the future, I am removing the link.

Comment: @MarkWallace Ah ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up version numbers here: [Microsoft Visual C++ - Internal version numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Internal_version_numbering).

Godbolt uses `_MSC_VER` separated by a dot, e.g. `1914` is `19.14` on Godbolt.